# Store or copy AXUIElementRef from callback

Tags: objective-c, struct, memory-management, axuielement

I'm trying to store an [AXUIElementRef](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/axuielementref?language=objc) provided by an `AXObserverCallback` callback. When the callback scope ends, I believe the struct gets freed and I'm no longer able to use it elsewhere.

Is there a way to retain or copy this ref into my own data structure?

Here is the relevant code:

```objectivec
AXObserverCreate(..., &observer_callback, ...);
AXObserverAddNotification(..., ..., kAXWindowCreatedNotification, this);
...
void observer_callback(AXObserverRef observer, AXUIElementRef windowRef,
                       CFStringRef notificationName, void* inUserData) {
    applications* apps = (applications*)inUserData;

    if (CFEqual(notificationName, kAXWindowCreatedNotification)) {
        // memory error when trying to use windowRef outside of callback
        apps->add_window_ref(windowRef);
    } else if (CFEqual(notificationName, kAXUIElementDestroyedNotification)) {
        apps->remove_window_ref(windowRef);
    }
}
```

I know this is easily possible in Swift since [this project](https://github.com/lwouis/alt-tab-macos/blob/9e03d5f6659f0bf2327712e1e70851267acf01c1/src/logic/events/AccessibilityEvents.swift#L62) does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate one level up in the documentation to [AXUIElement.h](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/axuielement_h?language=objc) where it says:

> Each accessible user interface element in an application is represented by an AXUIElementRef, which is a CFTypeRef. AXUIElementRefs (like all CFTypeRefs) can be used with all the Core Foundation polymorphic functions, such as CFRetain, CFRelease, and CFEqual."